# Azure IOT Hub Read CSV files from FTP Server

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am having a situation where i continuously receive csv files (every minute) containing sensor data on an FTP Server. I would like to make use of Azure IoT Hub to handle my csv files so that it is available for data analysis and visualization.  I would like to use stream analytics and store the data in Azure in some format (as the data is in time series format) for all the data that is available in the csv files for further analysis. Any pointers on how to proceed on this would greatly help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -3):

Follow this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-file-upload/#upload-a-file-from-a-simulated-device)

Convert file to Blob and push it. It will be stored in Blob storage and from there you can Analytics